# Difference with StringComparer and StringComparison

Tags: c#, string

What is the difference between the two? I've coded this just to practice string comparison etc however they both require difference ones.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> l = new List<string>(new string[] { "Hello", "Bye" });
            string x = "Stack";
            string z = "Stack";
            bool StrCmpr = z.Equals(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); //Here
            bool LisCmpr = l.Contains("hello", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); //Here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`StringComparison`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) is an enumeration which just tells the method which algorithm to use. [`StringComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class that handles the actual comparisons. There are some default static objects that handle certain cases, like in your code. But you could implement your own way of comparing strings however you want with this class, with the enumeration it isn't possible.